# webbrowser control c# only invoke first time next time not working

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2008

I am trying to extract some data from the website but the submitbutton invoke only first time in document completed event.after loading the first submitted page document completed event not executing
my code is

```
 private void b_DocumentCompleted(object sender, WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        WebBrowser b = sender as WebBrowser;
        string response = "";
        response = b.DocumentText;
        HtmlElement links = b.Document.GetElementById("btn1");
        links.InvokeMember("click");
        checkTrafiicButtonClick = true;
        MessageBox.Show("");
        ***// upto these working and loading second page after that i want to fill data   
           and want to submit but down line is not working and it should be work after    
           loading the page that i submitted how can i do these***

        HtmlElement tfrno = b.Document.GetElementById("TrfNo");
        tfrno.SetAttribute("value", "50012079");
        HtmlElement submitButon = b.Document.GetElementById("submitBttn");
        submitButon.InvokeMember("click");

    }
```

Comment: Doesn't btn1 click load the new page?

Comment: yes first page btn1 click executing and second page loadig but i want to fill input box in second page and want to submit

Comment: Just add a variable that keeps track of what page you are on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your comment, your code will not work as expected. After the first click the webbroser starts asynchronous page loading. You should do following:

```
private void b_DocumentCompleted(object sender, WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        WebBrowser b = sender as WebBrowser;
     if(b.Url.AbsoluteUri == "mydomain.com/page1.html")
     {
        string response = "";
        response = b.DocumentText;
        HtmlElement links = b.Document.GetElementById("btn1");
        links.InvokeMember("click");
        checkTrafiicButtonClick = true;
        MessageBox.Show("");
        return;
     }
        ***// upto these working and loading second page after that i want to fill data   
           and want to submit but down line is not working and it should be work after    
           loading the page that i submitted how can i do these***
     if(b.Url.AbsoluteUri == "mydomain.com//page2.htm")
     {
        HtmlElement tfrno = b.Document.GetElementById("TrfNo");
        tfrno.SetAttribute("value", "50012079");
        HtmlElement submitButon = b.Document.GetElementById("submitBttn");
        submitButon.InvokeMember("click");
        return;
     }
    }
```

Also note, that some parts of the page can be loaded from different source, for example in `iframe`, so you have to check proper `uri`

Comment: yes actually the second page some data is loded from iframe some another url how can i check the frame loading completed or not?

Comment: @eldhose DocumentCompleted will fire for every loaded url. Fund out the address of the frame using fiddler and check if it has been loaded then.